# Ruby on Rails: How do you seed the *_type column in polymorphic models?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, seed, polymorphism

I have a lot of data that I'm trying to seed into a polymorphic model in Rails 2.3.8. The association for all of the data is with the County model. The data looks like:

```
data = Datum.create([
  ...
  { :value => '14389', :value_type => County, :value_id =>'3103'},
  { :value => '59013', :value_type => County, :value_id =>'3105'},
  { :value => '17117', :value_type => County, :value_id =>'3106'},
  ...
])
```

The :value_type => County values lead to "undefined method `base_class' for String:Class."

I have tens of thousands of these values that I would like to seed into the database. They are similar to the values above except some are associated with the County model, some with the State model, and some with the City model. They are static values that will not be edited after seeding into the database.

How do I seed the model into the :value_type field?

(or... am I approaching this incorrectly and if so, how would you approach it?)

Edit: The relevant part of the schema.rb file:

Isaac -

```
create_table "data", :force => true do |t|
  t.integer  "value"
  t.string   "value_type"
  t.integer  "value_id"
  t.datetime "created_at"
  t.datetime "updated_at"
end

create_table "counties", :force => true do |t|
  t.string   "name"
  t.integer  "state_id"
  t.integer  "ansi_code"
  t.string   "ansi_class"
  t.datetime "created_at"
  t.datetime "updated_at"
end
```

I tried the following on the seeding, too, and it didn't work (County in quotes):

```
{ :value => '14389', :value_type => 'County', :value_id =>'3103'},
```

Comment: Can you post the relevant parts of your schema.rb?

Comment: Having `value`, `value_type` and `value_id` doesn't make sense. The Datum model would use `value_type` and `value_id` to go find the correct record in another table when you access it with something like `somedatum.value`

Comment: Jamie - I followed the Obie "The Rails Way" example on p. 215 where, in a Comment model there are `subject`, `subject_id`, and `subject_type` fields. The Comment model includes `belongs_to :subject, :polymorphic => true` and then other classes have `has_many :comments, :as => :subject`. 

My Datum model included the line `belongs_to :value, :polymorphic => true`. My County model included the line `has_many :data, :as => :value`.

Comment: Jamie's right. I haven't read that book, but I don't think you're interpreting it right. Another way of putting our confusion is: what is 14389 in your seed script? Like, what does that number mean? And if it's the county's ID, what's 3103?

Comment: You really should give your models more informative names than *Datum*. Everything is data.

Comment: Lars is correct, perhaps. I'm still wet behind the ears with Rails and learning my way around. Thanks for the suggestion. Issac: 14389 is the number of people living in the County with an ID of 3103.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You definitely don't need the "value" column in your schema -- just "value_id" and "value_type". Then your seed data should look like this:

```
...
{ :value_id => 12345, :value_type => "County" },
...
```

Note that "County" is a string in quotes.

Another alternative would be to do this:

```
{ :value => County.find(12345) }
```

And then Rails will automatically set the `:value_type` and `:value_id` columns for you based on the class name and id of the County record. This example might give you a better idea of what's going on. However, for thousands of records this would be much slower, so the first approach is probably better for this case.

Comment: That's certainly right, but what's unclear to me is what the OP is trying to do with `:value_id =>'3103'`

Comment: Based on the OP's schema, I'm hoping and assuming that he has a County record with the id 3103. To make this work, the County (and other potential 'Values', e.g. City, Region) tables would have to be prepopulated with records with those ids. If that's not the case, then more code is needed (something like `:value => County.new([other county attributes here])` might work).

Comment: Nick is correct. Sorry for the confusion with the naming. the `:value` is a population number. `:value_type` refers to the other model in the polymorphic relationship -- in this case, County. `:value_id` is the id number of the county (prepopulated).

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because you've done this in your model:

```
belongs_to :value, :polymorphic => true
```

And because you're trying to set the value column on the table too. Rails will not be able to tell the difference between you setting the association or the column via this method. To set the column use this:

```
self[:value] = "something"
```